# Creating column that accumulates value over years with Powerquery in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following input:

[image]

The output I am trying to achieve using Powerquery or VBA in Excel is:

[image]

It should calculate the given rows as shown in the **Comment** column.

The current solution I came up which is not working is:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "ABC")),
#"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Name", "Year", "A", "A+1 year", "Expected const A (A >= 2 years)"}),
#"Grouped Rows (Year, Name)" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Content", {"Name", "Year"}, {{"A", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows (Year, Name)",{{"Year", Order.Ascending}})),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Name"}, {{"Data", each let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1) in Table.AddColumn(a, "Accumulated A", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(a[Value],[Index]+1))) , type table }}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"Year", "A"}, {"Name", "Accumulated A"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Data"[Name]), "Name", "Accumulated A", List.Sum),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Pivoted Column", List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1)),
#"Demoted Headers" = Table.Transpose(Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Filled Down")),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Demoted Headers", [PromoteAllScalars=true]) in #"Promoted Headers"
```

Which basically only sums the column "A" and makes a pivot (+ fills the blanks with values from the previous year - that part is not present in the code snippet):

[image]

Anybody might suggest the approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Post sample data as text NOT images**

Code for powerquery. I've simplified column names. Change as appropriate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

process = (tbl as table, plus as number) =>
    let Source = Table.RemoveColumns(tbl,{Table.ColumnNames(tbl){2}, Table.ColumnNames(tbl){3}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{Table.ColumnNames(Source){2}, Table.ColumnNames(tbl){2}}}),
    ChangeYear = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Year", each _+plus, type number}})
in ChangeYear,

Current = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Year", "A"}),
PlusOne = Table.TransformColumns(Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Year", "A+1"}),{{"A+1", "A"}}),{{"Year",each 1+_, type number}}),
Future=Table.Combine(List.Transform ({2 .. 30}, each process(Source,_))),
combined = Future & PlusOne & Current ,
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(combined, each [Year] <= 2030),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Name", "Year"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([A]), type number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Year", Order.Ascending}})
in  #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

It basically cycles the far right column of the table 28 times, adding one to year each time, so we can eventually add them